Document with Grouped Table from Spreadsheet
I'm working on a script that will pull the data from a spreadsheet that contains two columns:

Company
Product

I want to create a new document based on a Google Doc template that has variables for Company and Product. For each Company listed in the spreadsheet, the products should be listed below the Company. For Example:



COMPANY 1




Product 1


Product 2






COMPANY 2




Product A


Product B



I've put together the following script:
function generateDocumentFromSheet() {
  // Open the Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YY');
  var dataSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('Data');

  // Get the data
  var data = dataSheet.getRange('A2:B' + dataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); 

  // Group Products by Company
  var companyShowMap = {};
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    var companyName = row[1]; // Assuming Company column is the second column (index 1)
    var product = row[0]; // Assuming Product column is the first column (index 0)
    if (!companyShowMap[companyName]) {
      companyShowMap[companyName] = [];
    }
    companyShowMap[companyName].push(product);
  });

  // Open the template Google Doc
  var templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById('XX');
  var body = templateDoc.getBody();

  // Replace placeholders with grouped data
  for (var company in companyShowMap) {
    // Duplicate the table section for each company
    var tableSection = body.copy();
   
    // Replace placeholders in the table section
    tableSection.replaceText('[[company]]', company);
   
    // Add rows for each Product
    var products = companyShowMap[company];
   products.forEach(function(product) {
      var newRow = tableSection.copy();
      newRow.replaceText('[[product]]', product);
      body.appendTable(newRow);
    });
  }

  // Create a new document with populated data
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.create('Populated Document'); // Change the title as desired
  var newDocBody = newDoc.getBody();
  newDocBody.appendParagraph(body.getText());

  // Save and close the new document
  newDoc.saveAndClose();
}

I'm getting the following error in the Add Rows for Each Product section:

Error
Exception: The parameters (DocumentApp.Body) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendTable.


Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "I've put together the following script:"? Do you already know the JavaScript basics?

essentially the error you're getting is from mixing types. In your code
body.appendTable(newRow);

"newRow" is actually a Body Document Element, which is intended to be the parent of any other element inside of a Google Document, such as Paragraphs, Tables, Images, etc.
Since there were some other potential issues with your function, I rewrote it how I personally would craft this bad boy. The biggest change in the flow is making the template stay unedited, but making a copy of the template and editing that document.
This function should do it. You will be able to change the formatting however you prefer in your template, and have the "Populated Document" reflect that row formatting for the Company row and the Product row.
 function generateDocumentFromSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ua9-f5flQd2GlP1-6_PiajL4DTppwNQtPMzQqRiomOw');
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const data = dataSheet.getRange('A2:B' + dataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const companyShowMap = {};
  const templateDocId = "15pufbbYFX9krBWR_VbNyF2d8lsP3rftCaj0zJDYIZNk";
  const focusDoc = DocumentApp.openById(DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocId).makeCopy("Populated Document").getId());
  const body = focusDoc.getBody();
  const [table] = body.getTables();
  const companyRow = table.getRow(0);
  const productRow = table.getRow(1);
  const companyIncrementer = 1;

  data.forEach(row => {
    const [product, companyName] = row;

    if (!companyShowMap[companyName]) companyShowMap[companyName] = [];

    companyShowMap[companyName].push(product);
  });

  for (const company in companyShowMap) {
    // Duplicate the table section for each company to append rows to
    const companyTable = table.copy()
    const products = companyShowMap[company];

    companyTable.appendTableRow(companyRow.copy()).replaceText('\\[\\[company\\]\\]', company);

    // Add rows for each Product
    products.forEach(product => companyTable.appendTableRow(productRow.copy()).replaceText('\\[\\[product\\]\\]', product));

    //clean up the table by removing the initial 2 rows
    companyTable.removeRow(0);
    companyTable.removeRow(0);

    body.appendTable(companyTable)
  };

  //remove the initial table
  body.removeChild(table);

  focusDoc.saveAndClose();
}

Of course, replace the IDs with your own 
